# How to change the position of sub SKViews with device orientation?

Tags: swift, position, skview

**How to change the position of sub SKViews with device orientation?**

My goal is to change the `position` of some sub-views in such a manner as explained by the following example:

The whole reason behind this question centers on he fact that the sub-view (**X**) is moveable. If the sub-view while in landscape mode is moved by a Game Controller close to the UIScreen's right edge and then the user rotates to portrait mode, this **X** will be **off-screen** when the SKScene is re-drawn with the orientation change.

Let's say that the `position` of a Game piece = `{x: 120, y: 10}` measured relative to the **center** of the `UIScreen`.

If I were to calculate that `Point` to reflect its coordinates = a percentage of the w,h of the `UIScreen`, that hypothetical `Point` would be `{x: percent*roomWidth/2, y: percdnt*roomHeight/2}` where:

```
roomWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
roomHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
```

Within my GameViewController, I have

```
#if os(iOS) && !targetEnvironment(macCatalyst)

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        
        setGameParms()
        showScene()   // redraw the whole SKScene based on the above Parms
        
    }   // viewDidLayoutSubviews
   
#endif

func setGameParms() {
  
    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        // e.g., change position of a Player
    else {
        // e.g., change position of a Player back
    }

}   // setGameParms
```

It's a Game, so obviously the Game Pieces move .. and as already stated, that's the problem.

In fact, I am dealing with only 2 sub-views. If there were more - what a pain!

**Isn't there a magic Swift function that can be called to perform the same math for many sub-views?**

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain if this is the **proper** solution - but it is a solution!

1. set theScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill, versus suffering with the cropping that comes with .aspectFill
2. I have mentioned that the central issue behind the question is that the pieces involved are **moveable**. SO, I decided to play with the limits of movement .. for example, restrict the horizontal movement to the right while in landscape orientation so that the object stays visible when rotated to portrait orientation.

I am not happy about the necessity of playing around a tad with these limits .. but I for now do not see any other choice, given my relative skimpy knowledge about rotation.